# Bluprism - what can "do" actually do?

Tags: blueprism

in navigation, with my element, I can choose the following actions :
"Do" "Focus" "Global Mouse Click" "Global Mouse Click Centre" "Verify"

Can anyone explain what a "do"-action can do ? Are there any predefined methods I can use (if so, where do I find these?). Can I define methods myself ?

[image]

Comment: Is this Blue Prism v6?

Comment: Yes, it's Blue Prism v6.

Answer (score 1):

Your spied element in Application modeler has "Allowed Actions" attribute in case of Java mode.

You can "Do" something that is listed there, like "Click" PushButton instead of GlobalMouseClick-ing it or "Open/Close" Combobox.

Comment: Brilliant, I tried one of the "Allowed Actions", and it worked just like you said.